# Find and display only the highest score in the table

Tags: javascript

I was hoping you could help me with my code..

I have an HTML table with dynamically added data.
So, I wanted to create a filter for it so the **same test** taken by the **same person** be removed and display only one per person and get only the highest score.

```html
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 2</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So it should only display Jonh Doe's Exam 1 with the score of 8.
But show both of Jane Doe's because it's two different exams..

Now, I have a script that search for the duplicates but I'm currently stuck..

```
var nTds = document.querySelectorAll('[title="Name"]'),
  tTds = document.querySelectorAll('[title="Test"]'),
  test = [],
  names = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nTds.length; i++) {
  names.push(nTds[i].textContent);
}

for (var i = 0; i < tTds.length; i++) {
  test.push(tTds[i].textContent);
}

const nCount = names =>
  names.reduce((a, b) =>
    Object.assign(a, {
      [b]: (a[b] || 0) + 1
    }), {})

const tCount = test =>
  test.reduce((a, b) =>
    Object.assign(a, {
      [b]: (a[b] || 0) + 1
    }), {})

const duplicates = dict =>
  Object.keys(dict).filter((a) => dict[a] > 1)

console.log(duplicates(tCount(test)))
console.log(duplicates(nCount(names)))
```

Thank you so much! any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you not filter the results before creating the table? (It is dynamic after all)

Comment: @A.Lau i wanted to make it like kind of has a check box above it that when it's checked it hides the duplicated entries but show it again when unchecked

Comment: Why pull the text out of the cells? I'd iterate over  them once, collecting name: test. When a duplicate is found, remove the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a checkbox button you can show/hide as you please. Let me know what you don't understand.

```js
function duplicate_hide()
{
  var table_rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

  var unique = {};
  var selection = ["Name", "Test", "Score"];

  for (row of table_rows)
  {
    var temp = [];
    for (select of selection)
    {
      temp.push(row.querySelector(`td[title="${select}"]`));
    }
  
    // Destructuring assignment
    var [the_name, the_test, the_score] = temp;

    the_name = the_name.innerHTML;
    the_test = the_test.innerHTML;
    the_score = the_score.innerHTML == "&nbsp;" ? 0 : the_score.innerHTML;

    if (the_name in unique && the_test in unique[the_name])
    {
      //same test, saved score is lower than current score, hide previous row
      if (+unique[the_name][the_test].score < +the_score)
      {
        unique[the_name][the_test].row.className = "hidden";
        unique[the_name][the_test].score = the_score;
        unique[the_name][the_test].row = row;
      }
      else
      {
        row.className = "hidden";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // Create new object if it doesn't exist on name
      if (!(the_name in unique))
      {
        unique[the_name] = {};
      }
      unique[the_name][the_test] = {score: the_score, row};
    }
  }
}

function duplicate_show()
{
  var table_rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
  for (row of table_rows)
  {
    row.className = "";
  }
}

function duplicate_check(event)
{
  if (event.target.checked)
  {
    duplicate_hide();
  }
  else
  {
    duplicate_show();
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="duplicate_check(event)" /> Toggle Me
</div>

<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
      <th> something else </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='odd'>
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
    <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
    <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
    <td title="Score">4</td>
 </tr>
  
    <tr class='even'>
    <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
    <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
    <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
    <td title="Score">5</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr class='odd'>
    <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
    <td title="Test">exam 2</td>
    <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
    <td title="Score">7</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr class='even'>
     <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
     <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
     <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
     <td title="Score">7</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr class='odd'>
     <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
     <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
     <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
     <td title="Score">4</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr class='even'>
     <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
     <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
     <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
     <td title="Score">3</td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I have this one person with 4 records with all same exams but it still leaves 2 rows and remove the other 2

Comment: @M.Y you'll have to show me what the data looks like

Comment: @M.Y given that this is in Kanji/Chinese, there might issues in that the browser won't know what to do, best thing would probably be to convert it into a unicode or something a browser would be more happy with. I'm not too familiar with handling non-English text

Comment: @M.Y The other possibility is that there's whitespace before/after the keys, meaning that you should use a `trim` to clean it up a bit

Comment: i see, I tried to add a record that doesnt have any kanji and it still leaves 2 rows. is it still because of the enocoding?

Comment: if it's not because of the language, I would just try using trim to clean up any possible before/after whitespace. If that still isn't the issue, then I'd double check the logic at each stage. I can't really do much without further data

Comment: just for the heck of it i tried combing your code with rob's (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42662872/7675768) I added his code at the end of duplicate_hide() and it has removed the unfiltered one.. lol but the thing is now, if the name test and scores are all the same it's removed completely so none of it is being displayed. >.<

Comment: @M.Y Well I can't see your website anymore so I can't help lol

Comment: oh sorry! it was messing my testing a while ago.. you can see it again now, I'd very much appreciate your help! the "Score Filter 2" is the combined code (yours and rob's). the last 2 row has the same name test and score so after filter it's completely removed.

Comment: @M.Y Score filter 1 is mine?

Comment: score filter 1 is rob's. it leaves a few data unfiltered. score filter 2 was yours i just tried adding his code at the end of it so the data with more than 2 duplicates are also filtered.

Comment: Is it working for you? Could you add my original code as a third filter so I can see what may be going wrong? If it's working for you then don't worry, since you worked it out.

Comment: i added yours as score filter 3. it only leaves 2 rows from 4 duplicates so i thought maybe its bc it only compares 2 values? so when the duplicate is 4~ it compares it separately and leaves the 2 with the higher values?

Comment: The reason why Superadmin is duplicating is because of the `nbsp;` you're using instead of 0, I'll take a look at the other ones.

Comment: @M.Y Okay I believe I have fixed the code, I forgot to reassign the values after the saved one was lower than the outside one. Should be okay now. Check the edit

Comment: YES! the duplicates has been fixed, Thnk you! :) though, with "佐藤 信夫" i think the highest score is 4 but it's showing 3.. other seems to be working perfectly

Comment: Oops, another mistake, it should be fixed now.

Comment: omg thank you! this is awesome! :D one last question, would it be totally different if i remove the row completely then reattach (on toggle) than just adding a hidden class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, come chat at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/137529/question-code-chat-personal?tab=general

Comment: I dont think I can :/ I just joined stack and I think I need reps for that >.< what I meant was below the table i have the csv exporter, so if i just hide the rows the csv file is still unfiltered. So i thought i have to remove it then reattach it again so it doesnt show up on the csv?

Comment: You could do it. Just store all the unwanted data into an array then just place them back in afterwards. I'm not sure how it'll affect the performance if you have a larger table though. I've heard that dom manipulations cost a lot. But if you're doing that, why can't you just check for the `hidden` class and not put that into the CSV?

Comment: ohhh I see! I'll try the excluding the hidden class. :) Thank you so much! you've been a very big help!

Answer (score 0):

please see the demo.If you want add a checkbox to show the rest scores,this code doesn't helped you,and you must grouped the data via [name,test] before render.so you must provide multi table instead,not one table only.the strcture may be like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Scores</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>02/11/2017</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02/11/2017</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<table class="test-table">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Test</th>
        <th> Date</th>
        <th> Score</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
        <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">Exam 2</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/babel">
    let highest = {};

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')).forEach((exam) => {
        const get = (name) => {
            return exam.querySelector(`[title="${name}"]`).textContent;
        };
        var [name, test, score]=[get('Name'), get('Test'), parseInt(get('Score'))];
        let key = [name, test];
        if (highest[key] >= score) {
            exam.parentNode.removeChild(exam);
            return;
        }
        highest[key] = score;
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Answers should not depend on libraries or other scripts that aren't tagged or mentioned in the OP.

Comment: the babel libraries that only support for me to write emascript in browser.

Comment: hi, what @RobG said.. and I i don't think I can make another table inside the table because the table is actually created by a plugin from wordpress.

Comment: I from China,I'm not good at English,so you must talk your question clearly.If you can't make tables inside the root table.the code of my answer could do it.you only replace `replaceChild` with hidden them.

Comment: @holi-java Thank you for answering! :) although i would prefer using pure javascript for this one

Comment: @M.Y it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making it too complex. Just loop over the rows in the table body and collect name, test, score and the row it's in. If you encounter a combination more than once, hide the lower score or show the higher score and update the saved score and row.

```js
var rows = document.querySelector('table').tBodies[0].rows;
var seen = {};
[].forEach.call(rows, row => {
  var name  = row.cells[0].textContent,
      test  = row.cells[1].textContent,
      score = Number(row.cells[3].textContent);
  if (seen[name] && seen[name].hasOwnProperty(test)){
    if (seen[name][test].score > score) {
      row.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      seen[name][test].row.style.display = 'none';
      seen[name][test] = {score: score, row: row};
    }
  } else {
    seen[name] = {[test]:{score: score, row: row}};
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td title="Name">Jane Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">Exam 2</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In some recent browsers, NodeLists (such as HTMLCollections like *rows* and those returned by *querySelectorAll*) have a *forEach* method that makes it simpler.

This also uses computed property names, which can be avoided but takes a couple more lines of code. If they're not supported, likely nor are arrow functions. Neither are an issue and are easily replaced.

Comment: He also wants to show the ones that have the highest score in the duplicate, so if John Doe's scores were swapped, your results would be wrong

Comment: hi, I tried this method too. I just couldn't figure out how to get the higher score when for example John Doe's first score is higher than his second one.

Comment: @RobG for some reason it still leaves some duplicated records. I have a few data and it will filter some and leave some unfiltered

Comment: @M.Y—Can you provide an example? This works off the text content, so any stray spaces or such will affect the keys. It would be better if the data was held in *data\** attributes or an object.